# Llamar funciones JavaScript en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Tengo un archivo JSP de un carrito de compra y para evaluar que servlet debe utilizar dependiendo de la accion de boton, con javascript relice un metodo para adherirselo, pero cuando le doy click al boton no pasa nada.

Este codigo es parte del head y tiene codigo java donde evaluo el rol del usuario mediante una sesion:

```
<head>
<title>Runner Store</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/<%=css%>">
<%
String js="";
if (session.getAttribute("rol") != null) {
    int rol = (Integer) session.getAttribute("rol");
    if (rol==1){
        js = (String)session.getAttribute("jsuser");
    } else {
        js = (String)session.getAttribute("jsadmin");
    }
}else{
    js = "main.js";
}
%>
<script src="js/<%=js%>"></script>
</head>
```

Bueno, la validacion hace lo que se espera, darle al src el js correspondiente, pero aqui el problema, tengo una funcion simple para adherirle al form el action y el method, al igual que a un input hidden que contiene el valor del id del producto que voy a añadir al carrito:

```
<% String funcag = "agregar()"; %>

<input type="button" class="boton" id="sendagbtn" value="Añadir al carrito" onclick="<%=funcag%>">
<input type="hidden" name="sendag" value="<%=a.getId()%>">; //esto es de un for each que me trae datos del producto.
```

y esta es la funcion del js:

```
function agregar(){
   var serv = '/RunnerStoreApp/AddCarrito';
   var met = 'POST';
   document.getElementById("sendagbtn").value = "Añadido al carrito";
   document.getElementById("sendagbtn").disabled = true;
   document.forms.formaction = serv;
   document.forms.formmethod = met;
}
```

Y aqui es donde llego, que cuando doy click en el boton, no se ejecuta.

Nota: soy novato con el JavaScript.

Comment: ya probaste llamando al metodo `agregar()` dentro de `onclick`

Comment: Si, pero lo estaba llamando con variables declaradas en Java, tenia que llamarla directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu código veo que estas mezclando Javascript y HTML con JSP, tu código JavaScript reside dentro de tu página final, por lo que la llamada a tu función `agregar()` desde el HTML no necesita pasar por JSP.
Si dicha función se encuentra dentro del documento HTML la puedes llamar directamente, no es necesario que hagas esto: `<% String funcag = "agregar()"; %>`

Te dejo un pequeño snippet sobre como llamar tu función con puro JavaScript/HTML y la respectiva llamada HTTP que veo que quieres hacer utilizando [XML HttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

```js
function agregar() {
  console.log('Función agregar llamada');
  var serv = '/RunnerStoreApp/AddCarrito';
  var met = 'POST';
  
  // Modificamos el botón mientras se realiza la llamada
  document.getElementById("sendagbtn").value = "Añadiendo al carrito";
  document.getElementById("sendagbtn").disabled = true;
  
  //Creamos la llamada HTTP
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Acción que quieres ejecutar cuando la llamada fue exitosa
      document.getElementById("sendagbtn").value = "Añadido al carrito";
    }
  };
  
  // Realizamos la llamada HTTP
  xhttp.open(met, serv, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="boton" id="sendagbtn" value="Añadir al carrito" onclick="agregar()">
<input type="hidden" name="sendag" value="idObjeto">
```

Comment: Ahora que arreglo lo de la llamada directa de la funcion javascript, me funciona, osea llama a la funcion, pero solo setea el nuevo value "Añadiendo al carrito" y se queda ahi, ahora pregunto, en este caso cuando hace el envio http, la pagina deberia recargar o no? en caso contrario si no recarga la pagina, el tiempo que tarda en devolver el resultado de la condicion this.readyState && this.status es inmediato? por que no muestra el seteo del value "Añadido al carrito".

Comment: El regreso de esta llamada sería inmediato en cuanto el servidor al que estas llamando responda, no es necesario refrescar la página.
Este nuevo problema que se te presenta ya involucra ver que está pasando en el servidor que estás llamando, por lo que te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta con detalles de este problema, ya que se queda fuera de tu pregunta original.

Comment: Pregunto: el tercer parametro del metodo open(met,serv,true) que significa ese booleano y por que esta true?

Comment: El tercer parámetro se refiere a si la llamada es syncrona o asyncrona, si es true significa que será asyncrona y tu código seguirá ejecutándose.
Sobre la URL, si el servidor que recibe las peticiones se encuentra en otro host, si debes de poner la URL completa, si sería el mismo, no es necesario.

Si requieres enviar algo dentro de la petición POST debes hacer algo así:
    `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
       urlencoded"); xhttp.send("name=Henry&lname=Ford");`